# autoreload and package causing TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

Tags: python, ipython

I have python code spanning several files which I packaged up for convenience, ending up with the following 3 files under my_package directory:

```
__init__.py
```

contents:

```
from file1 import *
from file2 import *
```

file1.py contents:

```
class Base(object):
    pass
```

file2.py contents:

```
from file1 import Base 
class Derived(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        return super(Derived, self).__init__()
```

I then execute in IPython:

```
>>>%autoreload 2
>>>import my_package
>>>t = my_package.Derived()
```

So far so good.
But then I make changes to file2.py, say adding a dummy attribute.
Now when I execute:

```
>>>t = my_package.Derived()
>>>      2 class Derived(Base):
>>>      3     def __init__(self):
>>>----> 4         return super(Derived, self).__init__()
>>>      5 
>>>      6 dumm = 'asdf'
>>>
>>>TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type
```

This doesn't go away until I restart the IPython console. Why doesn't autoreload take care of this correctly? Everything works if I put Base and Derived into a single module file rather than package.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43751455/supertype-obj-obj-must-be-an-instance-or-subtype-of-type)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not a user of IPython, so I can't say exactly what's happening, but I guess that this is a symptom of using `from file2 import *` in your `__init__.py` file.

When you're creating an instance of your `Derived` class using `package.Derived`, you're not getting the most recent version of the class, but the old version that was current when the package was first loaded and the `from file2 import *` statement was run. When you modified the module code and IPython reloaded it, that changed `package.file2.Derived`, but not `package.Derived`.

However, the old version of the class still has a reference to its module's namespace, and when it tries to look itself up by name in the `super` call, it finds the newer version of the class instead. This is why you get an error, as the two `Derived` classes are not the same.

You would probably avoid this issue if you accessed `package.file2.Derived` directly. That will always get you to the current version of the class which shouldn't have any issues with `super` calls. Note that if there are still instances of the class that were created before you modified the module, you may still have issues (but that's probably not very surprising).

Comment: This makes sense. I tried to use "from file2 import Derived" rather than *, but that didn't fix it unfortunately. It's strange that autoreload cannot figure out that package.Derived should be updated.

Comment: @Leo The error seems to happen when using `from A.B import C` if B contains a `__init__.py` file. That annoys me too much.

Answer (score 16):

In Python 3, using the new `super().__init__()` instead of `super(Derived, self).__init__()` solved the problem for me

Comment: IDK why is anyone stil using python2 :D

Comment: @Yesh, because python2 is used in all pre 2022 versions of Maya.

Comment: Came here after running into `super(Derived, self).__init__()` in a python 3.x codebase that doesn't test autoreload!